# Assign same numbers in different formats to contact

Tags: java

How do I assign same numbers in different formats to one contact?

In the stock Samsung phone app,

+1 8542569, 8542569 and 18542569 are all assigned to one contact when called: "Example USA" :

[image]

Even though "Example USA" only has +1 854-256-9 listed in the phone book:

[image]

This goes on for every country, not just the USA. Here's a New Zealand example:

[image]

^ Here, "New Zealand Example" has 91234567 listed.

And, I can call 91234567, 00 64 9-123 4567 or 6491234567 and they will all get assigned to "New Zealand Example" contact:

[image]

My question is: how can I do the same thing in Java, for every country just like the Samsung stock app?

Say I have 3 strings: 91234567, 00 64 9-123 4567 and 6491234567.
How will my app recognize that they belong to the same contact and that they're basically the same number?

I'm sure it can be done because Samsung did it :)

Again, I'd like the code to work for every country.

Comment: Every country has an international calling code format, which is ***very*** likely what's being used here to determine if a number belongs in another country.  I would also wager that implicit numbers without the international code (+1 for US) are interpreted based on the locale the SIM card is registered in.  However, "how to do it" is a fairly broad question in and of itself since it very clearly can be done, but there's a multitude of ways to go about it.  What particular efforts have you put forward, and where are you having trouble?

Comment: @Makoto I've tried exploring `regex` possibilities. But it has proven to be a very difficult task because code has to be written for every single country.

Comment: And I doubt this is the only way.

Comment: get a list of area codes and contry codes and do a `if ( (number+"").startsWith(contrycode[i])){ number = number.split(contrycode[i])[1]`

Comment: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber is probably all you need to know (and is probably the very library your phone uses)

Answer (score -1):

**Part 1:** Remove starting zeros. <s>They are useless.</s> They might be useful, but it would be easier to do it by removing them.
[This quora link with be a bit useful](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-all-mobile-phone-numbers-start-with-0)

Now countries have different number of digits in their phone numbers. Like, India has 10 which doesn't match New Zealand and USA.

**Assuming that each country has a specific number of digits in numbers after removing region specific codes.**

**Part 2:** You can create a multi-dimensional matrix, with `country code` and `number of digits after that`. Match for starting country codes, and then verify number of digits.

This method **may** have conflicts with different countries, but I lack knowledge about this thing.
Eg. of conflict:

```
Country A: country_code = +1, digits = 6
Country B: country_code = +12, digits =5

+1 234567
+12 34567
```

Comment: I am loath to say that starting zeroes are "useless".  Telephone numbers aren't like any other kind of number in that the leading zero is somehow magically discarded.  But, it depends on the country, format, and other factors before a zero matters or not.

Comment: On my personal experience I had say they might be creating more trouble. I haven't seen any case where 0s are usefull, but I'll edit.